# c# WinForms ReportViewer Performance issue using RefreshReport() and ServerReport.SetParameters()

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Currently I am writing a c# client application that uses the WinForms ReportViewer Control to display reports from a remote server.

I am having performance troubles with the ReportViewer Control, to be specific with the 2 methods **reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters()** and **reportViewer.RefreshReport()** – they both take a really long time to complete and **not just on the very first call**, but on each subsequent call as well.
SetParameters() takes 20 to 40 seconds (they vary greatly in time, some execute event okay fast) and RefreshReport() is a bit faster but still takes ages.

I don’t think the server is the culprit, as the **same report** viewed **using the browser renders pretty fast**, about a second tops.

The report in question doesn't matter as well.

When I break into the process and take a look at the call stack, I see a call to Socket.DoConnect.
So I thought that’s a good reason to start using fiddler and I installed it, disabled caching and fired up the app again to see which call takes that long to connect, but the performance issue was gone. By using a proxy I am having the same performance as the webbrowser.

FYI: I am using NTLM authentication in the following way: reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredentials() { Username = ... }

I don’t have a strong webbackground, so I guess my question is:
What should this tell me / What should I be looking into?
(Btw: Adding fiddler to my installation package is not the solution I am looking for :))

I am grateful for any pointers.

Take care,
-Martin

Comment: Did I miss something? If there is something unclear, I'll gladly elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the server fixed the problem for a few days at least.

I noticed some errors in the eventlog on the server and the IIS Management Console took a long time to fire up and was unable to connect to the local iis, so I searched the web and found http://support.microsoft.com/?id=946517 which matched the errors in the eventlog.

After requesting and installing the hotfix, the errors described in the kb article went away and since then, the reports are loading normally in the reportviewer as well as in the browser.

I am not sure what the exact differences between the reportviewer and the browser are, but I have yet to encounter the problem again.